# Python - Select from Pandas DataFrame based on cumulative sum

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column called 'contribution'. This column contains the percentage contribution of the data in each row to the total (i.e. the sum of 'contribution' = 100%). I would like to be able to select the top 70% of rows in terms of their contribution. How can I do this?

```
df.sort_values('contribution', ascending=False)
```

Comment: `df1=df.sort_values('contribution', ascending=False)`; `df1[df1.contribution.cumsum() >= 70]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [quantile()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
df[df.contribution > df.contribution.quantile(.3)]
```